# How to query Firestore for dates in a certain month in an array field

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is my cloud firestore data:

[image]

I want to bring the dates in the workdates list according to the selected month in the application, but I can't make the code in flutter, can you help me somehow?

Answer (score 1):

assuming you already fetched the employee model and you have selected a month, you can do something like this:

```dart
List<WorkDate> getEmployeeWorkDates(Employee employee, DateTime selectedMonth) {
  final nextMonth = DateTime(month.year, selectedMonth.month + 1);

  return employee.workDates
      .where(
        (workDate) =>
            workDate.date.isAfter(selectedMonth) && workDate.date.isBefore(nextMonth),
      )
      .toList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to query the `workdates` array field of your documents for just the month of the dates. The closest Firestore has is the `in` operator, but for that you need to specify the entire array item and not just one of the subfields in there.

The simplest workaround I can think of is to add an additional top-level array field to your document where you just the months of the `workdates` for that document in a queryable format, so for example:

```
workmonths: ['202207', '202208']
```

So there's a value in `workmonths` for any month that exists in the `workdates` field, but only one entry even when there are multiple dates within that month. To prevent duplicates, be sure to write to this field with the `arrayUnion` operation.

Now you can find the documents where there were work dates in July with:

```
collRef.where("workmonths", arrayContains: "202207");
```

Or the documents with work dates in July and August with:

```
collRef.where("workmonths", arrayContainsAny: ["202207", "202208"]);
```